# AutoFilter a Range: Run Time Error 1004 AutoFilter method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to create a UserForm.

I am following TheDataLabs video tutorial, but I am trying to adjust for 21 columns and thousands of rows of data.
I am stuck at the 32 minute mark. https://youtu.be/BdEMj4NNXAE?t=1921

The specific line:

```
shData.Range("A1:U" & iDataRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"
```

```vb
Sub SearchData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim shData  As Worksheet ' Data sheet
    Dim shSearchData As Worksheet 'SearchData sheet
    Dim iColumn As Integer 'To hold the selected column number in database sheet
    Dim iDataRow As Long 'To store the last non-blank row number available in Data sheet
    Dim iSearchRow As Long 'To hold the last non-blank row number availble in Search Data sheet
    
    Dim sColumn As String 'To store the column selection
    Dim sValue As String 'To store the search text value
    
    Set shData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set shSearchData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SearchData")
    
    iDataRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Application.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    sColumn = frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.value
    sValue = frmForm.txtSearch.value
    
    iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sColumn, shData.Range("A1:U1"), 0)
    
    'Remove filter fom data worksheet
    If shData.FilterMode = True Then
        shData.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    'apply filter on Data worksheet
    
    If frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.value = "Case code" Then
        shData.Range("A1:U" & iDataRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue
    Else
        shData.Range("A1:U" & iDataRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"
    End If
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, shData.Range("C:C")) >= 2 Then
        
        'Code to remove the previous data from SearchData worksheet
        
        shSearchData.Cells.Clear
        shData.AutoFilter.Range.Copy.shSearchData.Range ("A1")
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        iSearchRow = shSearchData.Range("A" & Application.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        frmForm.lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 21
        frmForm.lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "30,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70"
        If iSearchRow >= 1 Then
            frmForm.lstDatabase.RowSource = "SearchData!A2:U" & iSearchRow
        End If
    
    Else
    
        MsgBox "No record found."
    
    End If

    shData.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Check the value of `iColumn` just before attempting to apply the filter. You could do that by inserting the line `MsgBox iColumn`. My guess is that it's either 0, or does not contain a number at all but an error - which might suggest that an exact match to the value of `sColumn` does not exist in the header of your table.

Comment: Thanks CLR 
I have done the above and iColumn comes through as being the value of '2'
Which i think is right?

Comment: Maybe check `iDataRow` and `sValue` then - and that the sheet isn't protected?

Comment: Hi CLR,
Thanks for all your help
I didnt realise that tables had to be referenced separately from that of ranges, i have since returned it to a range and it now works... but i now have a different problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, thanks CLR for the help, it transpires that my range was in fact a table - i did not realise that needed to be referenced differently